# how do I lock down an app so that it can only be run by specific usergroup

Tags: windows-server-2008, terminal-server, remoteapp

I am running two servers, a domain controller and a terminal services server.

On the ts server I have published an app. I would like to set it up where only a specific group can access this app.

Can this be done? If so, where do I set it?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be much easier to restrict this app if you were running Windows Server 2008 R2 on the TS/RDS server.

Comment: so, just don't give them rights to that folder/program, and that will prevent the application from running then... good idea.

Comment: put that as an answer and I'll give you the credit :)